AddScheme() doesn't configure options
I'm trying to set up a custom authentication scheme in ASP.NET Core 8. I have created AuthenticationOptions and an AuthenticationHandler.
However the issue happens on startup, the line where options are configured is apparently never reached.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = ApiKeyAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = ApiKeyAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(ApiKeyAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.ApiKey = configuration["ApiKey"] ?? throw new Exception("No API key was configured");
    });

I'm sure it is not executing because if I put a breakpoint on that line it is never hit and if ApiKey is null the exception on the right side of the null coalescing operator is not thrown.
namespace API.Authentication.ApiKeyAuthenticaiton
{
    public class ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions>
    {
        public ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            UrlEncoder encoder) : base(options, logger, encoder)
        {
            ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions opts = options.CurrentValue;

            if (opts.ApiKey == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(opts.ApiKey));
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            // Validate API key
            
            if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValue("x-api-key", out var key)) return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing API key");
            if (key != Options.ApiKey) return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid API key");

            return AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(), Scheme.Name));
        }
    }
}

public class ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; } = null!;
}


According to this issue

The AuthenticationHandler constructor doesn't initialize Options because it doesn't have the scheme name yet. It's initialized after the authentication middleware calls InitializeAsync.


I had a test in my side and id worked well. But my codes has a little difference.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>("ApiKeyAuth1", options =>
    {
        options.ApiKey = builder.Configuration["ApiKey"] ?? throw new Exception("No API key was configured");
    });

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "ApiKeyAuth1")]
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}

public class ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder) : base(options, logger, encoder)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValue("x-api-key", out var key))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing API key");
        if (key != Options.ApiKey)
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid API key");

        var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test") };
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Tokens"));
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, this.Scheme.Name);
        return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        //return AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(), Scheme.Name));
    }
}

public class ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
}

By the way, I didn't meet the issue you mentioned -> the line where options are configured is apparently never reached.


Exactly my debugger isn't reaching the line where i configure options as well. I can't figure out why

Hi, could you please share a minimal sample for investigation?

By the way, I test in a .net 8 web api project. Could you please help confirm it?

In my side, if I kept your codes in ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler construction method, it will always throw null expcetion, do you faced this exception? I mean if (opts.ApiKey == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(opts.ApiKey)); will always be null so that excetion would be thrown.

The Options property is not initialized yet in the constructor. See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/57393
